# How to make truly additive “Addition” layer modes?

Tags: color, inkscape, gimp, color-spaces

[image: Addition layer and its treatment of bright colours]

This image summarises my mathematical struggles with the seemingly simple rule of “Addition” layer modes in different graphics applications (tested with GIMP and Inkscape). Since the greyscale layers of **RGB decomposed images** are subject to the same non-additive behaviour, even this is not viable. Neither does **linear light RGB mode** (via Image → Precision → Linear light) nor Composite space → RGB (linear) (in the layers context menu) come to our rescue, there still is 0.5+0.5=0.688 always.

I erroneously thought that the simple, [component-wise evaluated](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/graphics_tools/gimp_advanced_guide/gimp_guide_node55_001.html) formula **E=min((M+I),255)** [taken from the official documentation](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-layer-modes.html) means: values from layer **M** and **I** are *added* (and clipped if necessary). But this is obviously not the case.

Is there a way to obtain *plain stupid* component-wise addition, without such probably well-intentioned but badly documented Gamma mess?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I think this is probably a question for GIMP's developers. The maths behind their implementation is not really a graphic design question, even though it may be quite interesting.

Comment: It works in Photoshop just as expected.

Comment: That equation you linked to seems to relate to the Legacy Addition (I) Mode, and not the current GIMP 2.10 Default Addition mode. You can [switch between Legacy and Default modes in the layers panel](https://imgur.com/a/xKhpg6g). It looks like that page in the user manual hasn't been updated yet for the new Default Addition mode. I have no idea where you can find it. Perhaps ask the GIMP devs.

Comment: @Billy Kerr: I opened GIMP 2.10.18 and navigated via Help → Gimp Online → User Manual Web Site to https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-concepts-layer-modes.html, that is word by word the same as in my link, just with hard-coded version number in the URL. If GIMP help is indeed so horribly outdated, then this is a real issue for GIMP. But still doesn't explain why Inkscape does it the same way.

Comment: @Billy Kerr: Thanks for the pointer to the Legacy mode! That does the trick!

Comment: @H.Weirauch - it's not GIMP that is outdated.  Updates are fairly regular. It's the user manual that's not quite up to date.  Remember GIMP relies on volunteers to do this kind of work. It's not a commercial operation. Also note that equations for blend modes are a bit of a niche subject. Most users don't actually care about or need to know how it works under the bonnet, so although it may appear to be a real issue for you, it's less so for others.

Comment: As for Inkscape, perhaps the GIMP developers went for the same Addition behaviour in GIMP, so that they work similarly. There may have been some collaboration between GIMP and Inkscape developers over the Addition mode behaviour which led to the updated Default Addition in GIMP.  I don't know if this is a fact, but it would make sense.

Comment: Inkscape uses the CSS blend mode definitions for its layer blending algorithms (via filter in 0.92.x, via actual CSS blend mode in 1.0.x).

Comment: @Moini - then that seems to makes perfect sense.  The new default Addition mode in GIMP appears to be attempting the same kind of blend mode.